# Extract subdomain / domain from a text file using php

Tags: php, regex, dns

I've the following code which extracts domain name from the input and stores them in an array

```
foreach ($output as $domList)
{
  $extensionList = explode(",", "org,com,net");
  $pattern = '/(\s{0,}|\.)([-a-z0-9]+\.(' . implode("|", $extensionList) . '))\s{1,}/i';
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all($pattern, $domList, $matches);
}
```

matches[0] contains all domains extracted

How can i modify it to extract subdomains as well ?

Comment: can you give a sample of `$output`

Comment: $output = "contact us home support . This page is live! . Domains are test.com, test.sub.com. Visitors ....";

Answer (score 0):

Sample input and expected output would definitely help (I took creative license with the input). The idea in the new regex is to continue eating up anything that isn't .com,.org, or .net. Matches[0] should now yield all domains and subdomains.

```
$output = array("a" => " test.com  test.sub.com", "b"=> "a.com a.b.com b.c.a.com" );
foreach ($output as $domList)
{
  $extensionList = explode(",", "org,com,net");
  $pattern = '/\s*([-a-z0-9]+\.)+' . implode("|", $extensionList) . '\s*/i';
  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all($pattern, $domList, $matches);
   //   foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
   //     echo "matched: " . $val . "\n";
}
```

It shouldn't be difficult to tweak this to your needs.